# Understanding なんか in 「なんで鍵なんか閉めてんの？」

Tags: translation, nuances

I know that なんか has various uses, one of which is similar to a dismissive など, where `<NOUN>なんか` can mean "thing like NOUN" (dismissively).

**Question:** Is that what's going on here

> なんで鍵**なんか**閉めてんの？
>
> Why are you locking **things like** (なんか) this door?

Or is this employing another usage of なんか?